# Проверка на гласные и согласные буквы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если встречается согласная буква, то пропускать одну позицию в строке, если встречается гласная - то две.
В итоге должно получится слово `hello`. Проблема в том, что значение в `pos` после первого раза не меняется, как это поправить?

```js
var str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
var vowels = "aeiouy"; //гласные
var pos=0, res;
var res = str.charAt(0);
for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= vowels.length; j++) {
    if (pos == i) continue;//если есть позиция букву которой мы взяли то пропускаем 
    if (str[i] != vowels[j]) {//если согласная то 
      pos = i + 2;//позиция увеличивается на два
    } else {
      pos = i + 3;//если гласная то на три
    }
  }
  res += str[pos];//получаем букву
  console.log(res)
}
```

Comment: а как pos может быть одновременно равен и `i` и `undefined`?

Comment: ну вот, теперь pos - **всегда** undefined, и соответственно `str[pos]` так же `undefined`

Comment: почему в условиях `<= str.length`?

Comment: инициализируйте `pos`. Вообще начните скрипт с `"use strict";` сразу такие моменты отпадут

Comment: основная ошибка в том, что во внутреннем цикле вместо того чтобы просто проверить наличие буквы в массиве, идет изменение pos

Comment: попробуй прокомментировать каждую строку внутреннего цикла - он непонятно что делает

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Answer (score 3):

Наличие символа в массиве гласных можно делать с помощью `indexOf`, т.е. по факту вам не нужны 2 цикла с тремя счетчиками.

```js
var str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
var vowels = "aeiouy"; //гласные
var pos, res = "";
var i = 0;
while (i < str.length) {
  res += str[i];
  if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) {
    i += 3;
  } else {
    i += 2;
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: спасибо ,однако не  подскажите как поправить мой код, а именно почему в переменной pos ничего не меняется

Comment: @J.Joe, потому что ты всегда делаешь continue если pos==undefined, и нигде не заполняешь pos

Comment: @Grundy почему же?
` if (str[i] != vowels[j]) {
      pos = i + 2;
    }`

Comment: @J.Joe, до твоего последнего изменения кода вопроса - ты не доходил до этой строки, потому что перед ней было условие: `if(pos==undefined) continue;`

Comment: @Grundy поскажите, как именно можно мою писанину переписать чирбы сработало,потому что я не понимю пчему pos меняется только в первый раз

Comment: @J.Joe , ваш внешний цикл, например, при `i=1` будет  обрабатывать символ `i` в исходной строке, хоть этот символ в любом случае должен быть пропущен

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в логике: вместо того, чтобы определить *гласная* буква или *согласная*, на каждую букву pos меняется столько раз, сколько букв в массиве *vowels*

Кроме этого:

- проблемы со счетчиками (`i <= str.length;`, `j <= vowels.length;`) - в случае когда счетчик равен `str.length`, `str[i]` будет равен `undefined`, так как индексация идет с нуля.
- строка res меняется после изменения `pos`, но до проверок, что pos не выходит за границы строки. Поэтому в конце результата выводится много `undefined`
- `if (pos == i) continue;` - бесполезное условие, которое всегда `false`
- непонятно как связан счетчик `i` с переменной `pos`.

---

Если убрать недочеты, то может получиться так:

```js
// Если встречается согласная буква, то пропускать одну позицию в строке, если встречается гласная - то две.
var str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
var vowels = "aeiouy"; //гласные
var res = '';
for (var pos = 0; pos < str.length;) {
  res += str[pos];
  var isVowels = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) { // проверяем тип буквы
    if (str[pos] == vowels[j]) { // если гласная
      isVowels = true; // выставляем флаг
      break; // выходим 
    }
  }
  if (isVowels) {
    pos += 3;
  } else {
    pos += 2;
  }
  console.log(res)
}
```

вместо внутреннего цикла, можно воспользоваться [методом `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) как в ответе [@br3t](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685632/186999)

либо перевести строку в объект, с ключами соответствующими гласным буквам и использовать его:

```js
// Если встречается согласная буква, то пропускать одну позицию в строке, если встречается гласная - то две.
var str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
var vowels = "aeiouy".split('').reduce((acc, el) => acc[el] = true && acc, {}); //гласные
var res = '';
for (var pos = 0; pos < str.length;) {
  res += str[pos];
  if (vowels[str[pos]]) {
    pos += 3;
  } else {
    pos += 2;
  }
  console.log(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
var vowels = "aeiouy"; //гласные
var vowels = new Set(vowels.split(''));
var res = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === ' ')
    res += str[i++];
  res += str[i];
  i = vowels.has(str[i]) ? i + 2 : i + 1;
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: что это за код? Он явно делает не то, что описано в вопросе. Кроме того, у массивов нет метода has

Comment: Хотя если убрать лишний `if` и заменить `has` на [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) то получится еще одна вариация уже данных ответов

Comment: Ну с Set, это хотя бы не кидает синтаксические ошибки :) `split('')` можешь убрать, он не нужен

Comment: ну проблему то решает) ну и без второго вложенного цикла

Comment: а в чем смысл `if (str[i] === ' ')
            res += str[i++];`? У тебя в строке нет пробелов

Comment: ну более универсальная тема, вдруг в искомой фразе будет пробел

Comment: В задаче не оговорено, что пробел это какой-то специальный символ, поэтому в данном случае - это лишнее условие

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "hieeelalaooo";
var vowels = 'aeiouy';
var word = '';
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == ' ') {
      word += ' ';
  } else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) > -1 ) {
      word += str[i];
      i += 2;
  } else {
      word += str[i];
      i++;
  }
}
console.log(word);
```

Answer (score -1):

=> что-то типа того, осмысленней и по-современней, чем предлагали выше:

```
{
const str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
const glass = "aeiouy"; //гласные
const res = [];

str.split('').forEach(e=>
  glass.split('').includes(e) && !res.includes(e) ? res.push(e):''
)
console.log('гласные не повторяющиеся -> '+res.join(''));
}
```

///////еще короче:

```
{
const str = "hieeelalaooo"; //строка
const glass = "aeiouy"; //гласные

str.split('').reduce( (sum,e) =>glass.split('').includes(e) && !sum.includes(e) && sum.push(e)&&sum||sum, []
)
}
```