# Как написать логику удаления гласных из строки, не используя регулярные выражения, только цикл for of

Tags: javascript

```
 let result = '';
 let vowels = 'aeiouy';
  for(let letter of doc){
      if(vowels.indexOf(letter.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        result += letter;
      }
   }
   return result;
};
```

Comment: Один символ не может  быть равным строке из шести символов

Comment: Возможно, дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685627/Проверка-на-гласные-и-согласные-буквы

Comment: Нужен наверное какой то метод который найдёт подстроку?

Comment: @Эникейщик, это не все проблемы данного кода. Вижу ещё две - присваивание и возврат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую [new Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), чтобы каждый раз не тратить время на поиски и вынес его за функцию, чтобы не создавать каждый раз:

```js
const vowels = new Set('aeiouyAEIOUY');

const removeVowels = (str) => {
  let result = '';
  
  for (const symbol of str) {
    if (vowels.has(symbol)) continue;

    result += symbol;
  }
  
  return result;
}

const resFunc = removeVowels('Abracadabra');

console.log(resFunc);
```

Comment: нужно использовать только цикл  for of

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko Ну а там что по вашему?

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko Вас `new Set` не устраивает или что-то другое?

Comment: Прошу прощения,  я не правильно выразился, я сразу обратил внимание что это в сё в конструкторе new Set, у меня просто конкретно поставлена задача была.

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko У меня не всё в `new Set`, а только гласные буквы. Я просто не использовал массив т.к. кажый раз среди всех гласных искать находится ли там тот или иной символ - пустая трата времени. `new Set` - позволяет без траты времени на поиски определить есть ли в нём то что мне надо или нет

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду теперь знать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот к такому решению я пришёл.

```js
function removeVowels(doc) {
  let result = '';
  let vowels = 'aeiouyAEIOUY'
  for (let letter of doc) {

    if (!vowels.includes(letter)) {

      result += letter
    }
  }
  return result

}

let resFunc = removeVowels('Abracadabra');

console.log(resFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Метод indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
function removeVowels(doc) {
  let result = '';
  let vowels = 'aeiouy'
  for(let letter of doc){
       //// Условие: если в алфавите гласных букв(переменная vowels) нет буквы (letter), то мы её добавляем к результирующей переменной.
      if(vowels.indexOf(letter)<0  ){
        result += letter
      }
   }
   return result
  
}
let resFunc = removeVowels('Abracadabra')
console.log(resFunc)
```